# SESSION is not passing the value, gives empty slot in db while output no error in screen

Tags: php, mysqli

I been using `$mobile = $_SESSION['mobile'];` for my site as a user login confirmation or so.

It was working fine so far lately, until yesterday it ceased. giving empty input in DATABASE (when try to input the value using INSERT) and output no ERROR when executed the page.

My site page code as follows:

```
<?php 
    //15 2 2015
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]))
        header("location:usersignin.php");
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php 
    $mobile = $_SESSION['mobile'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobile = '$mobile' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                               
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                   
?>

<div class="clearfix otm">
   <h3 class="title">Add Money</h3>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('walletadd').submit();">
    <ul class="links">
      <li style="font-size:14px;"><strong>Add Money</strong></li>                     
    </ul>
    </a>                    
    <br>
<input type="hidden" name="preamount" form="walletadd" value="<?php echo ($row["wallet"]); ?>"/>
<div>
    <div class="circle">
        <img src="/assets/images/iicons/useraddmoney.png" alt="image" style="width:150px;height:150px;">                    
    </div>
<input type="text" class="useraddmoney" name="amount" form="walletadd" placeholder="Enter Amount Here"/>
    </div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Please note that on the above page, whenever i call the parameters of the respective user whose mobile number is $mobile outputs correct answer.

The backend php page as goes:

```
<?php include('sitepage.php'); ?>
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
<?php
$mobile = $_SESSION['mobile'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$preamount = $_POST['preamount'];

$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$amountdis = $amount * 0.02;

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO useraddmoneyhistory ( mobile, amountdis, amount, date, preamount)
VALUES ( '$mobile', '$amountdis', '$amount', '$date', '$preamount')";

if ($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql3 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "UPDATE users SET wallet = '$amount' + '$amountdis' + '$preamount'
WHERE mobile = '$mobile'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

echo '<a href="sitepage.php"></a>';
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

It actually works but inserts empty space in place of $mobile variable/.. 
Seems like Session is not passing value anymore. but it used to work earlier..

Couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Any advice is appreciated..

Comment: start sesion in your backend page also

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed The session is already being started in `backend.php` as they're including the site page in the line `include('sitepage.php');`, which does have `session_start();`

Comment: In backend, you do not check `$_SESSION['mobile'];` is set to anything before using it

Comment: echo $mobile and see if you are getting value there in back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start session in all pages

```
 session_start();
```

Comment: The session is already being started in `backend.php` as they're including the site page in the line `include('sitepage.php');`, which does have `session_start();`

Comment: Than also u need to start at the first starting of the page right after<?php

Comment: Why would you start the session twice?

Comment: well i just added `<?php 
 //15 2 2015
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]))
        header("location:usersignin.php");
?>` in backedn page.. and it worked..